# Google Performance API dailySubEntityType

Tags: python, google-perftools

I want to use the Google Performance API to fetch hourly the amount of clicks on my maps location. On the official documentation https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/locations/getDailyMetricsTimeSeries, there is an object `dailySubEntityType` which can be used to specify `timeOfDay`, but for some reason it isn't working. It also says that: The `DailySubEntityType` that the `TimeSeries` represents. Will not be present when breakdown does not exist, and I don't know what that means.

I already fetched without the `dailySubEntityType` and it had shown a value for this day, when i tried adding `&dailySubEntityType.timeOfDay.hours={hour}` with a for-loop for every our of the day, nothing was shown and no Error.